# How to give a custom type to an array key that is obtained by Object.values in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-morning-3q6gm?file=/src/App.tsx

The error:

> Argument of type '(key: Fiat) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) =>
> Element'.   Types of parameters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fiat'.

What I'm trying to achieve:
The quote expects a key of the type FIAT. Thus, when I am mapping I want to add the keys as FIAT type and not just a string. Is that even possible? If yes, how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to set the type of `Object.keys(accounts)` like so:

```
(Object.keys(accounts) as Array<keyof typeof accounts>
```

So your entire code then becomes :

```
export default function App() {
  const [accounts] = React.useState<AccountsMap>({
    "USD": 100,
    "AUD": 10,
    "BRL": 50
  });

  const [quote] = React.useState<Quote>({ USD: 2.5, AUD: 1.9, BRL: 5 });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      {(Object.keys(accounts) as Array<keyof typeof accounts>).map((key: Fiat) => (
        <p> {quote[key]} </p>
      ))}

      {(Object.keys(accounts) as Array<keyof typeof accounts>).map((key: Fiat) => (
        <p> {quote[key]} </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here we're suggesting to typescript to consider the array of strings returned by `Object.keys(accounts)` as the key type of typeof accounts, which in this case will be of type `Fiat` .

Answer (score 0):

Adding that remove the code below removed the Typescript error. However, I am not sure what this is doing and if it's the right way to fix the issue.

```js
{Object.keys(accounts).map((key: string) => (
    <p> {quote[key as Fiat]} </p>
))}
```

Comment: `key as Fiat` is forcing typescript to consider `key` as type `Fiat`. Whereas if we try to find. more generic way I feel it will be better. wdyt ?